# Can one set up a write-through cache with aufs?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, aufs

Say I have a system with two filesystems; one fast, small and unreliable (ie: ec2 ephemeral disk) and one slow, big and reliable (ie: ebs). Can I union mount the two filesystems so that the fast, unreliable FS acts as a write-through cache in front of the slow, reliable FS?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [brsync](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs2/brsync/README.txt). It's just like rsync but between branches.

With a bit of integration with [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) (ex.: if you don't write for 1 minute, launch brsync) or crontab and eventually with some kind of transaction/snapshotting management, 
you could get something fast and reliable (take in mind that you could lose some datas if something go down before sync ends).